# Printing passwords as encrypted in log file

Tags: python, logging, passwords, password-encryption

I have a Python code like below:

```
myargs = [param,/PASSWORD="{}",.format(myData['PASSWORD'])]
```

When I print it in my log file I use the following statement:

```
logging.info(myargs)
```

It prints the statement correctly, what I need is all passwords should be printed as `XXXX` or encrypted`(base64)`

Comment: "... or encrypted(`base64`)"  Encoding is not encrypting.

Comment: First off, `base64` is not encrypted, it's encoded. Every major programming language will easily be able to decode it so you might as well print it in plain text. Secondly, the solution is simple, just don't log passwords. There is no reason to do so and makes you extremely vulnerable.

Comment: @lanAuld i have to log the command like this -cmdparam SQLSVCPASSWORD=XXXXX, AGTSVCPASSWORD=XXXXX, SAPWD=XXXXXX, ConfigurationFile=C:\abc\xyz.ini

Answer (score 0):

First off, `base 64` is not encrypted, it's encoded. There is a big difference. Secondly, use hashing.

Check out the [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) module. There are various secure hash algorithms you can use. SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512 as well as RSA’s MD5 algorithm.

Though alone doing hashing is not secure due to [Rainbow Table](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rainbow%20table&oq=Rainbow%20table&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) attacks. Use salting along with hashing to make the passwords more secure. Short implementation of it taken from [here](http://pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/):

```
import uuid
import hashlib

def hash_password(password):
    # uuid is used to generate a random number
    salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
    return hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest() + ':' + salt

def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
    password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
    return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()

new_pass = raw_input('Please enter a password: ')
hashed_password = hash_password(new_pass)
print('The string to store in the db is: ' + hashed_password)
old_pass = raw_input('Now please enter the password again to check: ')
if check_password(hashed_password, old_pass):
    print('You entered the right password')
else:
    print('I am sorry but the password does not match')
```

Also, you can use werkzeug to help you with this. [This](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/54/) is a good snippet that you can modify and implement.